# Pandas: New column based on values of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns one with OLD id number that (column b) and another column with the NEW id number (a). I want to find out what name (c) corresponded to the old id number given the information I have in a and c.

```py
# Example dataset
print(df1)

# output
a  b  c
4  5  John
5  19 Joanna
1  4  Jenna
19 10 Jane
10 66 Johnna
16 16 JoJo
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```py
print(df2)

# output
b  d 
5  Joanna
19 Jane
4  John
10 Johnna
66 na
16 JoJo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df['d'] = df['b'].map(dict(df[['a', 'c']].to_numpy()))
```

Comment: I don't want to change the OLD index values.  I just want to know what names were assigned to b WHILE keeping b in the dataframe.

Comment: I also got this message: `<ipython-input-25-c839c882ca80>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

Comment: and how can this handle missing values? some values in b dont exist in a in my original dataset

Comment: It doesn't change the old values, it adds column 'd' with the name you want (as per your example).

Comment: but some values are in a but not in b or vice versa. Does it add "nan" to these? because i dont see any nan under the d column

Comment: There will be nans where there isn't a match yes. You can tag  .fillna('your_fill_value_here')   onto the end of my suggested line to handle those if you want to.

Comment: this assigns a specific value drawn from the dataset for d (for example, John) when b is nan instead of assigning nan for both b and d when b is nan

Answer (score 1):

It's a self join.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""a  b  c
4  5  John
5  19 Joanna
1  4  Jenna
19 10 Jane
10 66 Johnna
16 16 JoJo"""), sep="\s+")

df.merge(df, left_on="b", right_on="a").loc[:,["b_x","c_y"]].rename(columns={"b_x":"b","c_y":"c"})
```

|  | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | Joanna |
| 1 | 19 | Jane |
| 2 | 4 | John |
| 3 | 10 | Johnna |
| 4 | 16 | JoJo |

Comment: My actual dataset has hundred of thousands of entries. This wouldn't work..

Comment: it will do pretty well,  as other answer will use memory too.  memory usage can be reduced by using `loc` on left and right data frames to reduce columns.  If it's really enterprise scale data - use an enterprise platform.  Oracle will do 10M+ row table self joins efficiently